# Akka streams - why is an ActorSystem accepted as a Materalizer only when it is marked as implicit?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I'm looking at the akka streams quickstart tutorial and I wanted to understand how a piece of code works. The following code from the example prints out the values from 1 to 100 to the console:

```scala
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.{Done, NotUsed}
import akka.actor.ActorSystem

object Akka_Streams extends App{
  implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("QuickStart")
  val source: Source[Int, NotUsed] = Source(1 to 100)

  source.runForeach(i => println(i))
}
```

What I don't understand is, when I change the code to the following and remove the implicit, the code no longer works. I get a type mismatch error (shown below the following code):

```scala
object Akka_Streams extends App{
  val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("QuickStart")
  val source: Source[Int, NotUsed] = Source(1 to 100)

  source.runForeach(i => println(i))(system)
}
```

Error:

> type mismatch;
> found   : akka.actor.ActorSystem
> required: akka.stream.Materializer
> source.runForeach(i => println(i))(system)

Why did this work before but not now? the `source.runForeach` method takes a `Materalizer` type so I wonder why this was working at all to begin with? From what I can see, an `ActorSystem` is not a `Materalizer` or a sub-type of it so I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is related to how Scala compiler converts `ActorSystem` to a `Materializer`

It is done via [implicit conversions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-conversions.html) with following method

```scala
 /**
   * Implicitly provides the system wide materializer from a classic or typed `ActorSystem`
   */
  implicit def matFromSystem(implicit provider: ClassicActorSystemProvider): Materializer =
    SystemMaterializer(provider.classicSystem).materializer
```

It requires parameter `provider` to be `implicit`.

So having `implicit` key is allowing the compiler to take an implicit actor system when it needs an instance of a `Materializer`, and such conversion is done without any need to explicitly define a materializer in the scope.

Comment: Thanks for that. How did you find the `matFromSystem` conversion method? I thought this may have been happening somewhere but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Just follow the rules of how implicits are brought into the scope. One of the places compiler looks for them is companion object of involved types